# How to separate commands issued in a terminal from their output?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm realising that for 90% of my day I'm staring at the same part of my screen -- the bottom-left corner -- while I type commands and wait for output.  I'm starting to develop quite the neck strain, constantly staring downward like that and it got me thinking: surely there's a way for my terminal to separate the line on which I'm writing commands from the output that they generate, and therefore place the input line consistently at the top of the screen?

Something like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

⬇

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $ uname -om                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

⬇

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $ echo "Hello World"                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $ uname -om                                                                 |
| x86_64 GNU/Linux                                                            |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

⬇

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| $ uname -om                                                                 |
| x86_64 GNU/Linux                                                            |
| $ echo "Hello World"                                                        |
| "Hello World"                                                               |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this something that can be done with a creative Bash prompt, or maybe with tmux or something else like a GTK terminal emulator I've not heard of yet?

Comment: You should probably just raise your screen height.  I have a thick book under mine.

Comment: I thought about that, and it's obviously the easiest solution, but then I'm just moving the problem as I'd be constantly looking way-up to read the output.

Comment: Sounds like your monitor is too large for comfort or you are too close.  Or your main window is too large. Good posture is important in computer work.

Comment: Well when you're working at home, you've got options, but for laptop work you're rather restricted.  Positioning the cursor at the bottom of the screen where your hands are necessitates that looking-down.  Are you saying that what I'm looking for doesn't exist?

Comment: Maybe an external monitor would help then?  I haven't seen anything like what you suggest, but it could be written.  Might even be able to do it by setting the bottom part of the window as a scrolling region and have the prompt move between that and a non-scrolling region at the top.

Comment: One way or the other, product recommendations are off topic. There is [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: It doesn't need to be a software recommendation.  If there's a way to write a zsh theme or even pointers for how to write something like this would be appreciated.